# Classification of fixed points of system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider the system of differential equations given by $\dot{x} = -kxy$, $\dot{y} = kxy - ly$, where $k$ and $l$ are both positive. Find and classify all the fixed points.

I've made an attempt at this problem and have found the fixed points $(0, 0)$ and $(\frac{l}{k}, 0)$ but I'm having trouble classifying them. I've determined the matrix of partial derivatives and inserted the fixed points $(0, 0)$ and $(\frac{l}{k}, 0)$ respectively intending to calculate the eigenvalues of the resulting matrices.

Inserting the fixed points into the matrix of partial derivatives given by:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
-ky & -kx \\\\
ky & kx - l
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

and calculating their eigenvalues results in $\lambda_{1} = 0, \lambda_{2} = -l$ corresponding to $(0, 0)$ and $\lambda = 0$ with algebraic multiplicity $2$ corresponding to $(\frac{l}{k}, 0)$.

What would be the classification of the fixed points according to these eigenvalues? Perhaps there is a better approach to this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a matter of fact, all the points on the line $y=0$ are fixed points.